# Xpdf fit to page width in fullscreen mode

Tags: pdf

When I call the command:

```
$ xpdf file.pdf -z width -fullscreen
```

...it does not have the desired effect.

The individual options:

```
$ xpdf file.pdf -z width
```

...and:

```
$ xpdf file.pdf -fullscreen
```

...work as expected.

Is it possible to achieve the desired effect in xpdf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure enough. This appears to be a bug in `xpdf`.

You can switch to "width" view easily by tapping <kbd>w</kbd> as soon as xpdf opens, but there does not seem to be a way to make it behave from the command line. The only thing I could think of would be to hack it using expect or some sort of keyboard event routing to the X window to send it that keystroke when it starts up.

Comment: tapping `w` does not work too. In fullscreen mode I can't change the zoom. There is a message in commandline `Error: Invalid command syntax: 'zoomFitWidth'` when I'm pressing `w`

Comment: Hm. What version of xpdf? My 3.02 works find and allows me to change the zoom using that keystroke after launching with `-fullscreen`.

Comment: I have 3.02 too.

Comment: I found out that it works with `w` and `+` or `-`

Comment: Tapping 'w' works for me, but alas "xpdf -z width foo.pdf" from the command line still fails.

Answer (score 1):

I used Evince for this, but I grew tired of the scrollbars. When setting it up for Xpdf, I encountered this very problem. This is a workaround - without exaggerating ;) - that seems to do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh

# This allows you to use xpdf with options, although you're invoking
# it implicitly from Iceweasel. Just pick this script (instead of
# /usr/bin/xpdf) as your PDF reader under Preferences: Applications.

/usr/bin/xpdf -fullscreen -rv $1 &
while (( ! `wmctrl -l | grep Xpdf | wc -l` )) { sleep 0.1 }
xmacroplay "$DISPLAY" < ~/keydowns/xpdf &> /dev/null

# ~/keydowns/xpdf:
#
# KeyStrPress W
# KeyStrRelease W
```